# value name as string in assign function

Tags: r, string, object, assign

I want to use different data frames in a loop. I am having trouble with accesing the different data frames within the loop.

```
Data1<-data.frame(X=rnorm(100,2), Y=rnorm(200,2), Z=rnorm(200,2))
Data2<-data.frame(X=rnorm(300,500), Y=rnorm(300,500))
Data3<-data.frame(X=rnorm(500,200), Y=rnorm(20,200))

for (i in c(1:3)){
assign("CurrentData", paste("Data", i, sep=""))
colMeans(CurrentData)
}
```

The `assign` function does not do what I want because it thinks the second argument is a string and not the name of an object. How can I get around this?

Comment: Well, it was a string, now, wasn't it? (I think you check-marked the wrong answer. Using `get()` rather than `eval(as.name(...))` is considered more in keeping with typical practice.)  Generally newbies are not advised to get around difficulties with `eval`.) Better would have been building a list using `objname<-list(Data1=data.frame(X=rnorm(100,2), Y=rnorm(200,2), Z=rnorm(200,2)), Data2 = ...)`

Comment: Hi, I checked the answer I found most intuitive and it worked a treat for my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assign statement needs to be like this

```
assign("CurrentData", eval(as.name(paste("Data", i, sep="")))
```

The call to `as.name` converts the string to a symbol name, then the `eval` actually fetches the value of the symbol.

There are other ways to do it, but this clearly expresses the intent.

A simpler way to achieve what you want would be this

```
Data1<-data.frame(X=rnorm(100,2), Y=rnorm(200,2), Z=rnorm(200,2))
Data2<-data.frame(X=rnorm(300,500), Y=rnorm(300,500))
Data3<-data.frame(X=rnorm(500,200), Y=rnorm(20,200))

for (CurrentData in list(Data1, Data2, Data3)){
    somefunction(CurrentData)
}
```

Note I use a `list` to avoid all the data frames being coerced into one big vector.

Comment: This is just wrong. There is no `mean.data.frame` anymore. (Removed several versions ago.) And calculations inside for-loops are not printed or returned. And then there is always `fortunes::fortune("parse")`.

Comment: Well, one of them anyway: : `fortunes::fortune(106)` . One wonders is the addition of showMatches was driven by the proliferation of "parse" hits of fortunes: `fortunes::fortune("parse", showMatches = TRUE)`

Comment: Didn't want to change the OP"s code too much, and I did mention the problem with `mean`. Otherwise, I'd have presented something using `lapply`

Comment: Code that is erroneous should not be honored... rather it should be corrected.

Comment: Hi I have edited the mean statement to be colMeans. It was meant to be more of an indication that I was going to be doing some analysis/modelling within the loop and not something I was having difficulty with.

Comment: In which case, I've edited my simpler example to show the intent more abstractly

Answer (score 4):

See `?assign`

It's `assign(x, value)` where `x` is a variable name and `value` is an object to be assigned to that variable name

Currently, you have this:

```
...
assign("CurrentData", paste("Data", i, sep=""))
## This is equivalent to: CurrentData <- "Data1" 
...
```

You are assigning CurrentData the *string value*: "Data1", "Data2", "Data3" but not the values of the objects of the same names themselves.

Try using `?get`. Like so:

```
...
assign("CurrentData", get(paste("Data",i,sep="")))
...
```

BONUS:

You're better off with `colMeans(x)` for this purpose.